# Cannot retrieve cookie (JWT) from client side in Node.js (without using express)

Tags: node.js, cookies

I'm fairly new to nodejs so I'll try to explain the issue as best I can. I'm trying to authenticate and authorize a user with a JWT stored as a session cookie in a React frontend (port 3000) on my nodejs backend (port 5000). I'm not using express (trying to learn node first).

I have successfully authenticated the user against the db and returned the JWT. My thought was that when the user returns to the page in the same session, the client will make a post request to my nodejs server, providing the JWT to be authorized in the nodejs server.

I tried this in postman and see the stored cookie in the request header, BUT making the request from the client, the cookie is not present in the request header.

I have a feeling this is an issue with CORS/my client side headers but I'm honestly not sure where to look next.

Client side request:

```
import axios from "axios";

const authorizeUser = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/authorize", {
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

The section of my node index.js that is dealing with the authentication and authorization:

```
const http = require("http");

const {
  loginUser,
} = require("./controllers/Controller");

const authorizeUser = require("./middleware/auth");

const contentType = "'Content-Type' : 'application/json'";

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type, Accept"
  );

//sign in existing user
  if (req.url === "/login" && req.method === "POST") {
    loginUser(req, res, "users");
  }

 //authorize user with JWT
  else if (req.url === "/authorize" && req.method === "POST") {
    authorizeUser(req, res);
  }

else {
    res.writeHead(404, contentType);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: "Route not found" }));
  }
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}`));

module.exports = contentType;
```

Authorization middleware (auth.js). This where I'm trying to authorize the JWT. I haven't built this function out completely since I'm still just trying to retrieve the cookie from the request.

```
const authorizeUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.headers);

    res.writeHead(200, contentType);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

module.exports = authorizeUser;
```

Here is the function where I'm providing the JWT after credentials are initially confirmed. I tried setting httpOnly to true/false and secure to true/false for testing (why they're both commented out now):

```
const loginUser = async (req, res, collection) => {
  Results.selectCollection(collection);
  try {
    const credentials = await getPostData(req);

    const result = await Results.loginUser(JSON.parse(credentials));

    res.setHeader(
      "Set-Cookie",
      `token=${result.token}`
      // ; httpOnly=true; secure=false`
    );

    res.writeHead(200, contentType);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel a bit dumb, but managed to figure this out. Since I was using a post request, I should have been passing a payload, but I wasn't. My xhrField of withCredentials was the payload.

Changed my request to a get request, and updated my node to look for get requests and it works.

```
const authorizeUser = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/authorize", {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```